# PHP: Sort recursive array by given array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort array:

```
$tableColumns=array(
            'icons'                         => '',
            'mailnickname'                  => t('Internal code'),
            'telephonenumberextension'      => t('Internal extension'),
            'sn'                            => t('Last name'),
            'givenname'                     => t('First name'),
            'cn'                            => t('Username'),
            'level'                         => t('Role'),
            'has_photo'                     => t('Photo'),
            'workspace_workplace'           => t('Workspace'),
            'workspace_layout'              => t('Officelayout'),
            'company'                       => t('Company'),
            'department'                    => t('Department'),
            'group'                         => t('Group'),
            'position'                      => t('Position'),
            'supervisor_name'               => t('Supervisor'),
            'description'                   => t('Description'),
            'mail'                          => t('Email'),
            'mobile'                        => t('Mobile'),
            'telephonenumber'               => t('Telephone'),
            'extensionattribute1'           => t('City'),
            'updated'                       => t('Synchronized')
        );
```

by this order params:

```
$order_setup= array(
            'mailnickname',
            'telephonenumberextension',
            'sn',
            'givenname',
            'has_photo',
            'workspace_workplace',
            'company',
            'department',
            'group',
            'position',
            'supervisor_name',
            'mail',
            'mobile',
            'telephonenumber',
            'extensionattribute1',
        );
```

`$tableColumns` need to be sorted by `$order_setup`.

I try something like this but not work well:

```
$array_order = array_flip($tableColumns);

        usort($array_order, function ($a, $b) use ($order_setup) {
            $pos_a = array_search($a, $order_setup);
            $pos_b = array_search($b, $order_setup);
            return $pos_a - $pos_b;
        });

        $tableColumns_sorted = array();

        foreach($array_order as $o)
        {
            $tableColumns_sorted[$o]=$tableColumns[$o];
        }

        echo '<pre>', var_dump($tableColumns_sorted), '</pre>';
```

Comment: And columns not in `$order_setup`?

Comment: There's no *"recursive" (nested)* array in your code. Did you mean *associative*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended version of @evilReiko's version:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($order_setup as $field) {
    $newArray[$field] = $tableColumns[$field];
    unset($tableColumns[$field]);
}
$newArray = array_merge($newArray, $tableColumns);
```

Here you `unset` processed `$tableColumns`  values and after the loop - merge rest of `$tableColumns` to `$newArray`.

Comment: This will include ones not in `$order_setup`. Good :)

Comment: There is a lot of great answers but this is the best one. I can't belive that I'm after 15 years in PHP stack in this simple problem and solution. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
$tableColumnsSorted = [];
foreach($order_setup as $v) {
    $tableColumnsSorted[$v] = $tableColumns[$v];
}
```

There might be other ways to do this, but the above code does the job.

Notice, it will not include ones not in `$order_setup`.

Comment: Excatly what i had in mind, no need to make it complex

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for `array_intersect_key`. This automatically filters and orders the items of the first array by the keys of the second one. `array_flip` swaps the key and value of each item.

```
array_intersect_key($tableColumns, array_flip($order_setup))
```

Result:

```
array (
  'mailnickname' => 'Internal code',
  'telephonenumberextension' => 'Internal extension',
  'sn' => 'Last name',
  'givenname' => 'First name',
  'has_photo' => 'Photo',
  'workspace_workplace' => 'Workspace',
  'company' => 'Company',
  'department' => 'Department',
  'group' => 'Group',
  'position' => 'Position',
  'supervisor_name' => 'Supervisor',
  'mail' => 'Email',
  'mobile' => 'Mobile',
  'telephonenumber' => 'Telephone',
  'extensionattribute1' => 'City',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_order = array_merge(array_flip($order_setup), $tableColumns);
//Or you can do this way
$array_order = array_replace(array_flip($order_setup), $tableColumns);
```

Comment: Never seen array_flip with two arguments, what does that do? The manual only states one input.

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should be accompanied by an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
    foreach($table_columns as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($key, $order_setup)){
            $ordered_columns[$key] = $value;
        }
        else{
            $ordered_empty[$key] = null;
        }
    }

    print_r(array_merge($ordered_columns,$ordered_empty));
```